# Drop cap CSS styling in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I'm using pure CSS to style drop caps. My problem is IE9 - it seems to take no notice of the line-height value which sets the vertical position in every other browser I've tested including IE 8 and IE 10. I cannot find away to adjust the vertical position of the drop cap in IE 9 - can you help me?

See my site at: http://graphicviolence.co.uk and my CSS for my drop cap is:

```
.art-postcontent > p:first-of-type:first-letter 
{
letter-spacing:0;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#250607;
font-size:50px;
font-weight:normal;
float:left;
margin:5px 5px -7px 0; /* THESE VALUES SET TXT WRAP AROUND DROP CAP */
line-height:1; /* THIS SETS BASELINE POSITION OF DROP CAP */
}
```

Thanks
t

Answer (score 1):

as IE9 renders relative font sizes differently, you can solve this by referring to the document root glyph size, by using [font relative lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths).

use the `rem` unit on the `line-height` value, and correlate it with the font size set for  the document root (`html`).